# Dockerから画像・動画を表示させる方法

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv, docker

Dockerコンテナを立ててOpnecvをビルドしていれた後に

`import numpy as np

import cv2`

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video_name.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):`

```
      ret, frame = cap.read()

      gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

      cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break
```

`cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

と実行すると
`(frame:309): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`
のようなエラーが生じます

opencvでビルドする際にffmpegを入れているので動画の読み込みはできていると思うのですが、dockerからどのようにして画像や動画を表示させるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

DockerにはGUIがインストールされていないので、`cannot open display`が出ます。X Window System をインストールのも一つの方法です。

もう一つの方法は、Jupyter Notebookをインストールしてjupyter notebook上でcv2を動かす方法です。こちらの方が手軽です。

公式マニュアル
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d2e/tutorial_py_image_display.html
日本語の参考
https://qiita.com/fukuit/items/7fe137ac07654556cf87